# How to create custom menus with different path

Tags: views, 7

I want to create custom menus.

I created **dashboard** named menu, 
now i want to provide links under dashboard menu,

i created one link named myprofile.

and it is asking for path. i want to link it with user edit page who is logged in.

I have no idea regarding this.

Does anybody have idea regarding this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to give user view page then this :

1) You need to give path as `user`. That will take you to the currently logged-in user account.

Or if you want go to view edit page:

2) You can use [menu token module](https://drupal.org/project/menu_token) to give path as user edit page.You can use the token replacements to get to the user edit page.Hope this helps you.

3) You can use user/[current-user:uid]/edit once you have the menu_token module installed.But i dont know why its not working.

You can try installing [me aliases](https://drupal.org/project/me) module and give path as `user/me/edit`. This will give option for editing user account.Hope this resolves your current issue.

Comment: it goes to user view page. i want to go to on edit page

Comment: Most Welcome :)

Comment: i tried to add in path  user/[user:uid] . it shows this error 
The path 'user/[uid]/edit' is either invalid or you do not have access to it.

Comment: @rashmi: see my updated answer,the 3 point. Hope it helps you.